# Is it possible to enter Australia with a temporary Polish passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, australia, poland

I lost my Polish passport and I need to go back to Australia, where I hold a student visa. Can I get a temporary Polish passport to go back and then get the 10-year one once I'm in Australia?
A temporary Polish passport is valid for one year.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can travel to Australia with a Polish temporary passport.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in relevant part:

> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Poland with a temporary passport.

Remember to transfer your visa to your new passport before you travel. Since you must do this anyway, you probably may as well just get the 10 year passport, unless you need to travel urgently and can get the temporary passport more quickly.